# How to run Windows forms C# application with local database on client PC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-express, localdb

I have Windows Froms C# Application with local mdf database displaying data through sql connection in data grid view with no problems on Visual studio. When running this application on client PC It gives error " A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server" . Am i supposed to install whole Sql Server on Client PC or just a client instance ? and where to get it ? thanks

Connection string is `DataSource(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SqlLocalDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"`

Comment: If you are using the LocalDB version of Sql Server Express you need to just distribute and install the LocalDB.msi file. But you don't show your connectionstring so we can't tell you what do you need to install

Comment: Connection string updated in edit, Thanks for help

Comment: Yes, you need to distribute and install LocalDB.msi, it is part of the download of Sql Server Express. Be sure to install and use the same version used in your dev machine (or a later one, never a previous one)